# c++ std::function returns unexpected value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

```
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<bool(int)> set;

using namespace std;

set singletonSet(int a) {
    return [&] (int x) { return (a == x); };
}

bool contains(set s, int test) {
    return s(test);
}


int main() {
    auto first = singletonSet(5);

    auto r1 = contains(first, 10);
    auto r2 = contains(first, 5);

    cout << r1 << " " << r2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect this to print `0 1` but result is `1 1`

Beginner c++ labmda programmer here so sorry in advance if this is a basic error.

Comment: `[&]` captures by reference `a` which dies after the `return` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't capture `a` by reference, capture it by value. As-is, you're storing a dangling reference inside the lambda, and using it later leads to UB.

```
set singletonSet(int a) {
    return [=] (int x) { return (a == x); };
    //      ^
}
```

Comment: @shaz my pleasure :)